# How to make a bar chart with 2-level header in powerpoint?

Tags: excel, office365, bar-chart, powerpoint

I want to create a bar chart in Powerpoint with two level header, the exact result I want is as below:
[image]

I actually created this sample chart in excel.

Now I am going to duplicate it in Powerpoint. However the most I can do is one level header as below:
[image]

When I enter the "edit data" session, it seems extending the select grid (purple grid) to include the year level is impossible. Would anyone please help me?[image]

Comment: is there a reason that copy-and-paste the chart from Excel into PPT will not work?

Comment: good question. Because I don't want the powerpoint to link to that specific pivot table.. To my best knowledge, if i copy and paste from the excel, then the graph in the powerpoint will link to the pivot data on the original excel file. Please correct me if i am wrong. or how can i break the link after pasting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the "Select Data" dialog not the "Edit Data" dialog.
Then, select, "Edit" for the "Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels"
Then, re-select the axis to include both columns A and B.
Then select OK.
Boom, your chart works.
[image]